# Can I use money raised from Pre-ICO before start the ICO?

Tags: ico, presale

I was reading [this](https://hackernoon.com/hack-your-funding-with-an-initial-coin-offering-2a2a0614bddf) article

> Most serious projects have some sort of pre-ICO funding to finance the
>   marketing costs linked to the launch of an ICO.

I thought this funds (Pre-ICO funds collected
) were bound until the ICO end (**how else can investors be guaranteed?**).

Back to the main question, can I use money raised from Pre-ICO before start the ICO?

Comment: PLease could you guide me on where can a company list SAFT sale? We are really confused on how to receive money on Pre-ICO phase? Appreciate your help! Best regards,
Aman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  Pre-ICO funds have nothing to do with the ICO, which is just a crowdsale of tokens through a Smart Contract.  Pre-ICO funds are generally "vouchers" that you give to investors for a certain amount of tokens.  Then, in the creation of the token a list of addresses and balances are included according to how much each address invested.

EDIT: Pre-ICO funds can be forwarded to an ICO through a smart contract, but these funds would not be available in that case.  To use funds, dev teams will sell "vouchers" that guarantee a particular token balance for some address in the token contract code.

Comment: Look this https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/PresaleFundCollector.sol Pre-ICO funds are sent to the ICO

Comment: When you say "Pre-ICO funds are generally "vouchers"" ...means that investors are not guaranteed or these vouchers are referred to the crowdsale?

Comment: Yeah so looks for this specific contract you cannot use the funds, they are just being raised prior to the ICO up to a certain number investors (I'm assuming there is some benefit to getting in earlier than the ICO) and then forwarded to the crowdsale.  Lots of teams raise funds before an ICO through vouchers to have some money to get started.  Technically speaking investors are not guaranteed anything in a token sale.  They buy with no guarantee at all.  A voucher would be a commitment to include a balance for a particular address in the token contract code.